Azure Pipeline triggered by the wrong branch
I have a repo on Azure DevOps with three branches, dev and uat and prod. I also have a pipeline whose definition starts like below.
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - prod

variables:
  ...

When I push a change to the prod branch, this pipeline runs correctly. However, it also runs when I push a change to the dev or uat branches. Shouldn't it be that because I onl specified one branch in include, only that branch should trigger the pipeline?

I can reproduce the similar issue when multiple branches have the pipeline yaml files with the same name and the trigger field has the corresponding branch setting.

For example:
Prod branch -> YAML file name: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - prod

Dev branch -> YAML file name: azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev

To solve this issue, you can change the name of the yaml file in each branch and make sure the name is not repeated.
For example:
Prod branch -> YAML file name: azure-pipelines-prod.yml
Dev branch -> YAML file name: azure-pipelines-dev.yml
In this case, it should not trigger pipeline runs based on different branches.

Understood. I was under the impression that the version of the file in that branch is the what ADO runs. It seems like that is incorrect. Separate files should be fairly easy.
